# How do I make a condition statement which executes when one word matches?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, user-input

I am trying to make a conditional statement which executes it's content when a certain part matches it's condition!

```
string = input.nextLine();
If (string.equals("word")); {}
```

This however didn't work. What do I need to make this work?

Comment: Your code does not have a correct syntax. A brace is not closed in the second line.

Comment: just be aware that "certain part" and "word" are not exactly the same (for word I would suggest using regular expression {class `Pattern`})

Comment: I see multipl e problems here; 1. there is a ; after the if - so the if only handles the empty statement - so you should remove the ";". On the other hanbd you should think about switching to "word".equals(string) to avoid null pointer exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-). Also you have several typos in your posted example. `if` (not `If`). And you're missing a `)` and have a `;` where that should be. Anyway, it might look something like

```
String string = "a word";
if (string.contains("word")) {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```